# Do novas create a nebula? Could a planet survive if its star exploded in a nova?

Tags: nebula, nova

Does a nova, caused by runaway fusion in hydrogen accreted onto a white dwarf from a companion star, create a visible nebula?

If a planet were in a circumbinary orbit around a binary pair that produced a nova, would it survive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nova may leave behind a [nova remnant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_remnant): a shell of gas, expanding at about 1000km/s. In recurrent novae, they may be lit by light echoes from subsequent eruptions. They are much less massive than planetary nebulae, and at much lower energy than supernova remnants.

Novae displaying nebula shells or remnants include: GK Per, RR Pic, DQ Her, FH Ser, V476 Cyg, V1974 Cyg, HR Del and V1500 Cyg.

Planets in such a system would be bathed in high energy gas, this would not be enough to vaporise the planet, but it would make life on such a world extremely difficult.